# GCMBroadcastReceiver lacks WAKE_LOCK permission that is declared in manifest

Tags: android, android-manifest, google-cloud-messaging, android-permissions

I've implemented GCM as closely to Google's examples as I can, but the default GCMBroadcastReceiver is throwing a SecurityException for lack of the WAKE_LOCK permission.  I require it in the my manifest, though, so AFAIK it should have that permission at run-time.  Here's the relevant portion of my manifest:

```
<permission
    android:name="PACKAGENAME.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />

<uses-permission android:name="PACKAGENAME.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

<permission
    android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"
    android:protectionLevel="signatureOrSystem" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />

<application
    android:name=".App"
    android:icon="@drawable/app"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" >
    <service android:name=".GCMIntentService" />

    <receiver
        android:name="com.google.android.gcm.GCMBroadcastReceiver"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />

            <category android:name="PACKAGENAME" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

The exception I see in the log file is:

```
07-09 13:32:58.238: E/AndroidRuntime(2723): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start receiver com.google.android.gcm.GCMBroadcastReceiver: java.lang.SecurityException: Neither user 10072 nor current process has android.permission.WAKE_LOCK.
07-09 13:32:58.238: E/AndroidRuntime(2723):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2126)
07-09 13:32:58.238: E/AndroidRuntime(2723):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:123)
07-09 13:32:58.238: E/AndroidRuntime(2723):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1197)
07-09 13:32:58.238: E/AndroidRuntime(2723):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-09 13:32:58.238: E/AndroidRuntime(2723):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-09 13:32:58.238: E/AndroidRuntime(2723):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
07-09 13:32:58.238: E/AndroidRuntime(2723):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-09 13:32:58.238: E/AndroidRuntime(2723):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-09 13:32:58.238: E/AndroidRuntime(2723):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
07-09 13:32:58.238: E/AndroidRuntime(2723):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
07-09 13:32:58.238: E/AndroidRuntime(2723):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-09 13:32:58.238: E/AndroidRuntime(2723): Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Neither user 10072 nor current process has android.permission.WAKE_LOCK.
07-09 13:32:58.238: E/AndroidRuntime(2723):     at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1327)
07-09 13:32:58.238: E/AndroidRuntime(2723):     at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1281)
07-09 13:32:58.238: E/AndroidRuntime(2723):     at android.os.IPowerManager$Stub$Proxy.acquireWakeLock(IPowerManager.java:279)
07-09 13:32:58.238: E/AndroidRuntime(2723):     at android.os.PowerManager$WakeLock.acquireLocked(PowerManager.java:285)
07-09 13:32:58.238: E/AndroidRuntime(2723):     at android.os.PowerManager$WakeLock.acquire(PowerManager.java:264)
07-09 13:32:58.238: E/AndroidRuntime(2723):     at com.google.android.gcm.GCMBaseIntentService.runIntentInService(GCMBaseIntentService.java:235)
07-09 13:32:58.238: E/AndroidRuntime(2723):     at com.google.android.gcm.GCMBroadcastReceiver.onReceive(GCMBroadcastReceiver.java:46)
07-09 13:32:58.238: E/AndroidRuntime(2723):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2119)
07-09 13:32:58.238: E/AndroidRuntime(2723):     ... 10 more
```

Comment: Note: I've tried this on a 4.0.4 device and a 2.2 device and I don't get the exception on the 2.2 device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wasn't calling GCMRegistrar.onDestroy() in the onDestroy() method of the activity in which I registered to receive messages. For some reason that caused it to complain about not having WAKE_LOCK, but only on the 4.0.4 device.

Answer (score 0):

You should use:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
```

instead of:

```
<permission
    android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"
    android:protectionLevel="signatureOrSystem" />
```